# How do I escape reserved words used as identifier in Informix

Tags: database, informix

One can use delimited identifier in JDBC query and it works with below databases even for a non reserved keyword with below delimiters:

SQLServer: Square bracket => `[select]`

Postgres, Teradata, Oracle, Sybase and DB2: double quote =>  `"select"`

HIVE and MYSQL: backtick => `` `select` ``

Informix documentation says double quote can be used as delimiter to escape, but it does not work.

Any insight will be helpful.

Comment: A lot of the time, you don't need to use the delimited identifiers: `CREATE TABLE select (table INTEGER NOT NULL, integer CHAR(20) NOT NULL)` etc works OK — as does `SELECT select, integer FROM table` (unless JDBC tries to interpret the SQL!)  When you do need to use delimited identifiers, you must use double quotes, and you must have DELIMIDENT set in the environment (the value doesn't matter much; `export DELIMIDENT=1` is conventional).  This has been supported 'forever' (since about 1990, IIRC — it wasn't in earlier versions, but you shouldn't have been using those for 15+ years anyway).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the informix JDBC version 4.10 (not sure if it is supported in previous versions) you can pass the DELIMIDENT=Y parameter either in the connection string or through a properties list.

```
DELIMIDENT 
When set to Y, specifies that strings set off by 
double quotation marks are delimited identifiers
```

Check out the documentation: [Informix environment variables with the IBM Informix JDBC Driver](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.jdbc_pg.doc/ids_jdbc_040.htm?lang=en)